# Making sense of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $f(x)$ be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\textbf{(}x^3+2x+1\textbf{)}$. Then $f(x)=p(x)+\textbf{(}x^3+2x+1\textbf{)}$ for some arbitrary polynomial $p(x)$ belonging to $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ (here $\mathbb{Z}_3$ denotes the integers modulo $3$). We seek a "nicer" form for $f(x)$.

First of all, we may write $f(x)=p(x)+k(x)(x^3+2x+1)$ for some $k(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. By the Division Algorithm, we have $p(x)=q(x)(x^3+2x+1)+r(x)$ for some $q(x),r(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ such that either $r(x)=0$ or $\deg(r(x))<\deg(x^3+2x+1)=3$.

In the case that $r(x)=0$, we have $f(x)=q(x)(x^3+2x+1)+k(x)(x^3+2x+1)=(q(x)+k(x))(x^3+2x+1)$, so $f(x)$ is just the zero element of the quotient ring. On the other hand, if $\deg(r(x))<\deg(x^3+2x+1)=3$, then write $r(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and we have
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=q(x)(x^3+2x+1)+ax^2+bx+c+k(x)(x^3+2x+1)\\
&=ax^2+bx+c+(q(x)+k(x))(x^3+2x+1),
\end{align*}
$$
so in reality we can write $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c+\textbf{(}x^3+2x+1\textbf{)}$. When $r(x)=0$ just set $a=b=c=0$, so we have found a nicer form for $f(x)$.

Note that I am using $\textbf{bold}$ parentheses to denote *ideal*, and regular parentheses to denote multiplication.

> Is this line of reasoning sound? And is it true that we can generalize this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this looks good.

The general idea is: if $f(x)\in\mathbb F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial over a field $\mathbb F$, then $\mathbb F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is a field as well as an $\mathbb F$-vector space of dimension $n:=\deg(f)$. A basis is just the images of $1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}$ in the quotient space. So in this case the basis is the images of $1,x,x^2$ (as you have with the $a,b,c$ coefficients). In terms of writing an element of the quotient space, it is just of the form $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\langle f(x)\rangle$ for some $a_j\in\mathbb F$.